# How to return a blank page

Tags: plugin-development, admin

I can't seem to figure this out, how do I return a blank/white page in the admin area from a plugin page?

Edit:

How do I stop the default ui from loading and return an empty body instead?

Comment: May you please elaborate? Your question is very broad, providing an example helps

Comment: Is it intended to be added to at some point? Like a settings page? Or will it be one of those "This Page Was Intentionally Left Blank" pages? I find it very simple to render a blank page simply by omitting a semi-colon here and there... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a blank page that's been created in a plugin like so:

#### Example: `blank-page.php`

```
<?php
// Blank PHP page...
```

Use the following function:

```
add_filter( 'some_tag', 'wpse_238008_blank_page', 99 );

function wpse_238008_blank_page() { // Template with an empty page
    define( 'PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
    return PLUGIN_PATH . '/path/to/blank-page.php';
}
```

Replace the following to suit your needs

- `some_tag` - Name of the filter to hook the function to
- `/path/to/blank-page.php` - Location of your blank page in your plugin

Your question isn't very clear when you say:

> *...how do I return a blank/white page in the admin area...*

If you can update your question to specify where you want to see this exactly, I can give you an updated answer.